# Saving different variable types using sscanf

Tags: c

I want to read different elements written in a file and save them to different types of variables. The file I read only has one line  `key, value1, value2, value3`, for example `10, abc, 5, 2.35`.

I am able to find the file, open it and read the line. However, I am running into trouble when it comes to storing the values to the variables. I tried using sscanf since the format of the line in the file will always be the same but when I print the lines, I get back incorrect different values. What do I need to change?

```
#define MAX_LEN 1024

int get_value(int key, char *value1, int *value2, double *value3){
    char name[1000];
    FILE *f;
    char line[MAX_LEN];
    char *k = 0;

    // Change directory where we work.
    if(chdir("FilesPractice1") == -1){
        perror("Error while changing directories.");
        return -1;
    }

    // Convert key to the name of the file.
    snprintf(name, 1000, "%d.txt", key);

    // Open the file.
    if((f = fopen(name, "r")) == NULL){
        // If the file doesnt exist, return -1.
        perror("Error: element with key value does not exist.");
        return -1;
    }

    // Get values and store them.
    fgets(line, MAX_LEN, f);    
    printf("%s\n", line);

    sscanf(line, " %s[^,], %s[^,], %d[^,], %lf", k, value1, value2, value3);

    // Printing the values.
    printf("%s\n", value1);
    printf("%p\n", (void *)value2);
    printf("%p\n", (void *)value3);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Many functions can fail, and you check for many failures (which is good). But you forget to check for `fgets` failing. And you also forget to check what `sscanf` returns.

Comment: As for your problem, there's no such format as `%s[...]` or `%[...]s`. The format is *only* `%[...]`. And it can only be used to read strings, there's no possibility to use it to parse any other type. Since the `%[...]` format is so complicated and hard to use, I recommend you use some other way to split and parse the strings. For example using `strtok` to split on the comma, then use e.g. `strtol` or `strtod` to parse strings into integers and `double` values, respectively.

Comment: `"Error: element with key value does not exist."` is not a good error message.  Suppose you have a permission issue, in which case the user gets a message that looks like `Error: element with key value does not exist.: permission denied`  It would be better to just write `perror(name);`

Comment: rule #2 of scanf. always check the return (#1, always pass pointes)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are multiple problems with your code, as suggested in the question comments but the output problems is in this lines:

```c
    printf("%p\n", (void *)value2);
    printf("%p\n", (void *)value3);
```

`value2` and `value3` are pointers (to `int` and to `double`). The value of a pointer variable is the address in memory of some other value. You use `value2` and `value3` correctly on `sscanf()` (I assume that the function `get_value()` is also called correctly and `value1`, `value2` and `value3` are valid pointers) but you do not print the read values but the pointers (i.e. their addresses in memory).

The two lines above should be:

```c
    printf("%d\n", *value2);
    printf("%f\n", *value3);
```

This way you print the values stored at those memory addresses, not the memory addresses.

If you wonder why the previous `printf()` line works fine, this happens because a string in C is identified by its address in memory and this is exactly what `value1` is.
`*value1` is not the entire string but only its first character.

Answer (score 0):

To parse `"10, abc, 5, 2.35\n"` into a `int *, char *, int *, double *` and with some level of error checking,

```
// sscanf(line, " %s[^,], %s[^,], %d[^,], %lf", k, value1, value2, value3);
int n = 0;
sscanf(line, "%d , %3[^,] ,%d ,%lf %n", 
    &key, value1, value2, value3, &n);
if (n == 0 || line[n]) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Bad line <%s>\n", line);
} else {
  printf("%d\n", key);
  printf("%s\n", value1);
  printf("%d\n", value2);
  printf("%g\n", value3);
}
```

- `" "` scans optional whitespace.  It never fails.
- `"%n"` records the scan offset.  If scanning got that far, and no extra junk, `n == 0 || line[n]` is false.
- OP has not described the maximum length for string to store in `value1`.  Assume it is 3 (so `value1` points to a buffer of at least 4.
- Unclear what OP wants to do with the first integer read.  OP's code, with `char *k = 0;` errantly attempts to save that integer text into a invalid location leading to *undefined behavior* (UB).  Using `&key` here does not change the caller's `key`.
- Some spaces in the format are such to allow white-space after the *value* and before the `','`.